# export html to docx jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to export HTML data to docx file. please help me. I tried  wordexport.js but it's not working.

```
 <script src="js/FileSaver.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.wordexport.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $("a.word-export").click(function(event) {
            $("#page-content").wordExport();
        });
    });
    </script>
```

but its not working.. its only  export in .doc formate not in .docx

Comment: Assuming you are using https://github.com/markswindoll/jQuery-Word-Export (as you didn't say) - did you read what it does?

Comment: Are you asking how to get wordexport.js to generate a docx? Or if there's another plugin that would do this?

Comment: yes sir.. how to get wordexport.js to generate a docx?

Comment: if have any other plugin.. for export html to docx .. then plz tell me

Comment: wordexport.js "*This plugin takes advantage of the fact that MS Word can interpret HTML as a document. *" - saves as MHTML - you're never going to get this as a true docx.  Searching for a plugin is off topic.

Comment: In jquery.wordexport.js, line 74 change `saveAs(blob, fileName + ".doc");` to `saveAs(blob, fileName + ".docx");` - now it's saving as a "docx" in the same way that it currently saves as a "doc" (protip: neither is actually correct as you'd know if you read the project page).

Comment: saveAs(blob, fileName + ".doc"); i  already changed it.. and saved it  in .docx file..  but when i open that.. its show error..( the file is corrupt  cannot be open)

Answer (score 2):

See https://codepen.io/agamj474/pen/gdQroo

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Export-Html-To-Word-Document-With-Images-Using-jQuery-Word-Export-Plugin/FileSaver.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Export-Html-To-Word-Document-With-Images-Using-jQuery-Word-Export-Plugin/jquery.wordexport.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $("a.word-export").click(function(event)      {
            $("#page-content").wordExport();
        });
    });
    </script> 
<a class="word-export" href="#">Click me</a>
<div id="page-content">hello world<div>
```

this works for me.

Comment: sir plz check  the extension.. i want to save it in .docx  right now its saving  in .doc